# Basic and simple view, add, edit and delete functionality

Tags: javascript, html, mvc, angular.js

I want to know what needs to improve with my application.  Maybe there is a better way instead of what I am using currently.

**index.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Angular JS</title>

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="lib/JSON3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>My App </h1>
</div>  
<div ng-view>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**list.html:**

```
    <section>
    <a href="#/new">New</a>
</section>
<section>
    <select ng-model="orderRecord">
        <option value="Id">Id</option>
        <option value="LastName">LastName</option>
    </select>
    <label>Ascending</label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" checked/>
    <label>Descending</label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" value="reverse"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
</section>
<section>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in logs | filter: query | orderBy: orderRecord:direction">
            <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Mi}}</td>
            <td><a href="#/details/{{logs.indexOf(item)}}">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

**details.html:**

```
    <section>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id: <input type="text" ng-model="log.Id" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FirstName: <input type="text" ng-model="log.FirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LastName: <input type="text" ng-model="log.LastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mi: <input type="text" ng-model="log.Mi" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</section>
<section>
    <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="Update(log)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="Delete(log.Id)"/>
</section>
```

**new.html:**

```
    <section>
    <table ng-controller="NewController">
        <tr>
            <td>FirstName: <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LastName: <input type="text" ng-model="LastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mi: <input type="text" ng-model="Mi" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" ng-click="Create()" value="Create "/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

**app.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'logController'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    }).
    when('/details/:itemId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
    }).
    when('/new', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/new.html',
        controller: 'NewController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}]);
```

**controller.js:**

```
    var logController = angular.module('logController', []);
var logData = null;

logController.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('testws.asmx/GetUsers', {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.logs = data.d;
        $scope.orderRecord = 'Id';

        logData = $scope.logs;
    })
} ]);

logController.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.logs = logData;
    $scope.log = logData[$routeParams.itemId];

    $scope.Update = function (log) {
        $http.post('testws.asmx/UpdateUser', JSON.stringify({ Id: log.Id, FirstName: log.FirstName, LastName: log.LastName, Mi: log.Mi }), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $location.path("/list");
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert(err.Message);
        });
    };

    $scope.Delete = function (id) {
        $http.post('testws.asmx/DeleteUser', JSON.stringify({ Id: id }), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $location.path("/list");
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert(err.Message);
        });
    }

} ]);

logController.controller('NewController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.Create = function () {
        var user = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            LastName: $scope.LastName,
            Mi: $scope.Mi
        };

        $http.post('testws.asmx/AddUser', JSON.stringify(user), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $location.path("/list");
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert(err.Message);
        });
    }
} ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting,

a readable Angular submission, I quite like it.

The only trouble I see is that `controller.js` has some serious copy pastage, you might want to consider a helper function for this part:

```
    $http.post('testws.asmx/AddUser', JSON.stringify(user), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $location.path("/list");
    }).error(function (err) {
        alert(err.Message);
    });
```

only the URL and the original data is different for your call to `'testws.asmx/DeleteUser'` and `testws.asmx/AddUser`.

I like how this code seems compatible with older IE's without too many hacks.